# Returned type character varying(70)[] does not match expected type

Tags: postgresql

I need help to review following query,
I have table as follow :

```
CREATE TABLE "MasterDivision"
(
    "DivisionID" bigserial NOT NULL,
    "DivisionName_EN" character varying(70) NOT NULL,
    "DivisionName_HI" character varying(70) NOT NULL,
    "DivisionCode" character varying(70) NOT NULL,
    "StateID" bigint NOT NULL,
    "CreatedBy" bigint NOT NULL,
    "UpdatedBy" bigint NOT NULL,
    "CreatedIP" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    "UpdatedIP" character varying(70) NOT NULL,
    "IsActive" boolean NOT NULL,
    "CreationDate" date NOT NULL,
    "UpdationDate" date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_MasterDivision_DivisionID" PRIMARY KEY ("DivisionID")
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "MasterDivision"
OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE "MasterDivision" TO public;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE "MasterDivision" TO postgres;
```

and i created following custom type :

```
create type type_selectmasterdivisionwithpagging
as
(
    row bigint,
    DivisionID bigint,
    DivisionName_EN character varying(70),
    DivisionName_HI character varying(70),
    DivisionCode character varying(70),
    StateID bigint,
    StateName_EN character varying(70),
    StateName_HI character varying(70)

);
```

and the following function...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION selectmasterdivisionwithpagging("PageNumber" integer, "PageSize" integer, "WhereClause" text, "OrderByClause" text)
RETURNS SETOF type_selectmasterdivisionwithpagging AS
$BODY$declare 
    _SQL text;      
Begin   
IF $1 <> -1 and $2 <> -1  then

_SQL:='Select * ' ||
      'from ' ||
      '( ' ||
        'SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ('|| $4 ||' ) AS Row' ||
            ',MD."DivisionID" ' ||
            ',MD."DivisionName_EN" '||
            ',MD."DivisionName_HI" '||
            ',MD."DivisionCode" '||
            ',MD."StateID" '||
            ',MS."StateName_EN" '||
            ',MS."StateName_HI" '||
        'from "MasterDivision" as MD ' ||
        'left join "MasterState" as MS ' ||
        'on MD."StateID"=MS."StateID" ' ||
        $3 ||

      ' ) as t' ||
      ' where 1=1 and t.Row between ' || ((($1-1)*$2)+1)||' and ' || ($1*$2) ;

    RETURN query execute _SQL;              
else        
    RETURN query execute    'SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ('|| $4 ||' ) AS Row' ||
                    ',MD."DivisionID" ' ||
                    ',MD."DivisionName_EN" '||
                    ',MD."DivisionName_HI" '||
                    ',MD."DivisionCode" '||
                    ',MD."StateID" '||
                    ',MS."StateName_EN" '||
                    ',MS."StateName_HI" '||
                'from "MasterDivision" as MD ' ||
                'left join "MasterState" as MS ' ||
                'on MD."StateID"=MS."StateID" ';
end IF;
end;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
COST 100
ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION selectmasterdivisionwithpagging(integer, integer, text, text)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

All above query executes fine but when i use `select selectmasterdivisionwithpagging(1,2,' where 1=1 ','Order by MS."StateName_EN"')` it gives error :

**`ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
    DETAIL:  Returned type character varying(70)[] does not match expected type character varying(70) in column 7.`**

Let me know if more information is required.
thank you all

Comment: First, *please* rewrite that dynamic query using `format(...)` with the `%I` identifier-specifier, and with the `USING` clause; it makes it a bajillion times more readable, especially if you use a multiline quote like `$sql$ SELECT blah blah $sql$`. The exact error tells me that you're returning an *array* where a scalar `varchar` is expected.

Comment: Can you show the structure of `"MasterState"` table?

Comment: AS I was working along with team and one of fellow member didn't understand the difference between character varying() and character varying()[] so that's why i was getting error and that made my mind twist..thank you ..

Answer (score 5):

1. Please stop using `EXECUTE` when you don't have to.  If you do, use a parameterized form.  Your current function is vulnerable to all sorts of in-function sql injection.
2. Stop writing functions that *depend on* SQL injection vulnerabilities to work.  If I put in your where clause `'1=1; DELETE FROM "MasterDivision"; --'`  then you will get a wonderfully nasty surprise.
3. Your error implies that `"MasterState"."StateName_EN"` is not the type you believe it is.  Check there.  It seems to me that you probably have this as a varchar(70)[] instead of a varchar field.

Comment: I may be missing something but how can you tell if it's `StateName_EN` that doesn't have the matching type? From what I can see, it could be `StateName_HI` just as easily. Other than that, I agree with all your points.